# Hartshorne Prop I.4.9

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Hartshorne Proposition I.4.9 says:

> Any variety $X$ of dimension $r$ is birational to a hypersurface $Y$ in $\mathbb{P}^{r+1}$.

The start of the proof is as follows:

The function field $K$ of $X$ is a finitely generated extension field of $k$, so by a theorem, $K$ is separably generated over $k$. Hence we can find a transcendence base $x_1, \dots, x_r \in K$ such that $K$ is a finite separable extension of $k(x_1, \dots, x_r)$.

**Question:**

The definition of $K$ separably generated over $k$ (according to Hartshorne) is there is a transcendence base $\{x_i\} \in K$ such that $K$ is a separable algebraic extension of $k(\{x_i\})$. Why in the proof above is Hartshorne able to claim the extension is finite? There are certainly separable algebraic extensions that are not finite ($ \bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$) so I must be missing something about the function field $K$.

Thanks.

Comment: Being a finite extension is the same as being algebraic and finitely generated.

Comment: Ah yes! I've forgotten too much field theory. Thanks.

Comment: If I may add to the question: Why does the hypersurface he defines (obtained by the relation the $y$ has with the $x_i$) has function field $K$?